# How to understand the USDA Demand/Supply report ?

Tags: commodities

Need you help .. 
Have couple questions about the [Wheat Report](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/files/ht_charts/snd_cbt.pdf)

1. M Acres stands for ? Million acres ?
2. Yield Bu/Acre , can anybody explain this calculation ?
3. Stocks use ratio % , how the calculation works ?

   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *M Acres* is million [acres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acre), as you suggest
2. *Bu* is [bushel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushel), in theory a volume of 8 US dry gallons, but apparently for wheat at 13.5% moisture it represents a weight 60 pounds.  *Bu/Acre* is therefore an average yield: with some minor rounding $\frac{2309}{43.9}\approx 52.7$ in the first column
3. *Stocks/Use ratio* seems to be the stocks at the end of the period divided by the total use (domestic and exports) in the period so in the first column $\frac{1181}{2222}\approx 53.2\%$

Comment: Sir can you explain me 2 answer more simple ? )) Can't understand the mathematics ..

Comment: Production in 2016-17 (the first column) was about $2,309$ million bushels harvested from about $43.9$ million acres, giving an average yield of $\dfrac{2309000000}{43900000} \approx 52.7$ bushels per acre